# Bloquear traducción de sitio

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tengo un sitio desarrollado en DotNetNuke asp.net, el mismo es para realizar exámenes o quiz en ingles a estudiantes de primaria. hay alguna manera de bloquear o prevenir que puedan traducir el sitio? ya que hoy uno de los estudiantes al parecer tenía activo el traductor de sitio y el quiz le salía completamente en español. No tengo ningún paquete de idiomas en mi sitio, solo el idioma por defecto que es el ingles.

Answer (score 3):

Agregue `translate="no"` a su etiqueta `<html>`, así:

```
<html translate="no">
```

> [Referencia MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/translate)

---

Esto debería funcionar, pero es menos efectiva porque es específico de Google y existen otros servicios de traducción.

Agregue esta etiqueta entre `<head>` y `</head>`:

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
```

> [Referencia](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812)

---

Podría usar un método o ambos juntos así:

```
<html lang="en" class="notranslate" translate="no">
<head><meta name="google" content="notranslate" /> </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar `translate="no"` a tu etiqueta `<html>` de tu página Master, o de aquellas páginas específicas en que lo necesites.

```html
<html translate="no">
```

Asimismo, puedes colocar la clase `notranslate` a aquellos elementos específicos que no quieres que sean traducidos.

```html
<div class="notranslate"></div>
```